# asp.net mvc 3 telerik grid how to specify the button display type in page navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

How can I change the style of first prev next last button in Telerik Grid. In nopCommerce I see text for this buttons but on admin site I see images (|< < ... > >|). I wonder how to change text to images for this controls?
Thank you for the answers.

Not wanted
[image: text prev next buttons]

Wanted
[image: image prev next buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include this code at the bottom of view file:

```
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
    .DefaultGroup(group => group
        .Add("telerik.common.min.css")
        .Add("telerik.vista.min.css")
        .Add("telerik.rtl.min.css")
        ))
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
    .jQuery(false)
    .jQueryValidation(false)
    )
```

Now I see Telerik graphics correct.

Best Regards